# Typescript Interface SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier at interface name

Tags: typescript, interface

I'm new to Typescript and I'm still figuring my way out, I searched this problem everywhere otherwise I wont be asking this question. I have a SyntaxError at the interface name and don't know how to solve it. Here is my short code:

```
interface Cars {
    name:string
    model:string
    topSpeed:number
    colors:string[]
    speedPrint(carSpeed:number):void
}

class BMW implements Cars{
    name = 'BMW X6'
    model = 'S'
    topSpeed = 320
    colors = ['cobalt red','phantom blue','white']
    speedPrint(topSpeed:number):void{
        console.log(`My car top speed is ${topSpeed}`)
    }
}
```

and this is the error:

```
app.ts:1
interface Cars {
          ^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

Comment: You need to provide far more info. See my partial answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no Typescript syntax error in your code. You can see that [it has no errors at all in the Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMJygZ2QbwFDKHIhwC2EAXJmFKAOYFGkD2AJhADZU32OFjMADgGVBECKwogArqQBG0PsgTMOzLN1og6AbQC6SzGIkAFLWAAUCDKPGSZ86AEoKAN2bBWeAL548CDjhMbAAhAFkAdWRgUkEOCHJwbHQsfCJiMhQAXmQAcnCogA0ANlylFnYOZBzc4TL0gRFjVmrkAGYAJgAGJRU1LFadXJU5OA4wZCgJXIAaXMEACzhwZlJkOQ5pCFncgHcF4Ehcg3SjOzNQS0bbCSlZBSgXd0809KIVEExVCAA6NToLAADMIAT2UGGQjWQZwk0WwABIcNdmt5AU4lL5fHggA).

But from the stacktrace it appears that you are trying to execute the Typescript directly from Node.js as if it were Javascript. That would explain the error because Javascript does not support interfaces; it's a Typescript thing. You would need to compile compile the *.ts files to *.js using a tool like `tsc`, `esbuild` or `deno`, or you can even run Typescript directly using `ts-node`.

I can't give you a more specific answer without you providing more info about your setup, the command you executed that produced that error, etc.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, I was trying to get the logs in the VS Code like the tutorial I`m following but I think I missed something there.

Comment: That was the first thing i thought of after reading your answer, but I couldn't because I don't have a 15 reputation yet.

Answer (score 7):

I was facing the same error but I did the following and it works:

1. Install ts by typing this command in the terminal `npm install -g typescript`
2. After this type `tsc filename.ts`
3. Then `node ./file.js` (not ts) and see what gonna happen on the terminal

Answer (score 2):

I think instead of run node .ts you can run

1. tsc .ts
2. node .js
   Because when you run the first command, it will generate the equivalent javascript file corresponds to your typescript file.